# How to change a WebEx button on Note 3 found on the phone call screen

Tags: calls, samsung-galaxy-note-3

I just got a Note 3 and use WebEx app for work.  When I went to use the phone I saw that my "Add Call" button that used to be on the top left side of my options on the phone call connected screen is now showing a WebEx button.  Anyone know a way to change it back to the default setting of "Add Call" without deleting the WebEx app?

Answer (score 0):

known issue with Samsung Kitkat build, this is not a WebEX app issue and has been reported to Samsung:
http://kb.webex.com/WBX82788